# Wrap div around a hidden div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div "d1" and it contains a child div "d2". d2's visibility changes every time a particular button is clicked. What I need is to wrap d1 around its other contents when d2 is hidden and expand when d2 is visible.
Its something like this:

```
<div id="d1">
    <p>Content which is visible all the time</p>
    <button onclick="changed2()">Alter d2 visibility</button>
    <div id="d2" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to know if anything like this is possible through HTML or CSS without using things like Bootstrap.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what do you want to do with the parent div when the child div is hidden? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Try style="display:none"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display:none` and `display: block` instead of using `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`

as `display:none` will hide the element completely and its space.